# How to pass -m argument to sambal gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, samba

I have downloaded the sambal gem. Here is my smbclient command which I know works:

```
smbclient \\10.9.167.71\Dept -U CORP\thinger -m SMB2
```

I want to instantiate a sambal client object using those exact same parameters. Here is what I tried:

```
client = Sambal::Client.new(domain: 'CORP', host: '10.9.167.71', share: 'Dept', user: 'thinger', password: '--no-pass')
```

`-m SMB2` gets left out of the equation, but I know it has to exist in order for this to work. Reviewing the documentation I see no way to pass this argument. So then it's not surprising I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    3: from test.rb:6:in `<main>'
    2: from test.rb:6:in `new'
    1: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/sambal-0.2.2/lib/sambal/client.rb:29:in `initialize'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sambal-0.2.2/lib/sambal/client.rb:67:in `rescue in initialize': Unknown Process Failed!! (Failed to connect): "Failed to connect" (RuntimeError)
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sambal-0.2.2/lib/sambal/client.rb:64:in `initialize'
test.rb:6:in `new'
test.rb:6:in `<main>'
```

Is there a way? Reviewing this turns up nothing I can see, but it is plausible I am just not experienced enough to understand:

https://github.com/johnae/sambal/blob/master/lib/sambal/client.rb

I want to try to avoid using the `smbclient` commands directly in my ruby script - it seems, simply, a painful way to do things. I will do it if I have to, though.

Answer (score 0):

The `-m` flag to smbclient is an alias to `--max-protocol`.

This flag can be set in sambal by passing the the `max_protocol` option to the initializer. With your other options, this will look like:

```
client = Sambal::Client.new(domain: 'CORP', host: '10.9.167.71', share: 'Dept', user: 'thinger', password: '--no-pass', max_protocol: 'SMB2')
```